# От какого лица и в какой форме писать комментарии в документации на английском?

Tags: документация, комментарии

Допустим, я пишу комментарий к функции для документации. Мне нужно описать что она делает. Форматирование пока опустим. Предположим, это функция загрузки файла с сервера. По-русски я напишу что-то вроде этих вариантов:

```
/*
 * Функция загрузки файла
 *  или
 * Загрузка файла
 */
```

Я слабо владею английским. В русском языке принято описывать алгоритм от третьего лица, но на английском часто встречал описание от второго лица. Как правильно написать такую функцию на английском? Нужно ли подразумевать 'it' и писать от третьего лица? Или вовсе писать в неопределенной форме? Сейчас я пишу так:

```
/*
 * Loads a file
 */
```

Comment: А от второго лица это вообще как?

Comment: Язык программирования какой?

Comment: @andreymal Ошибся. От первого конечно. Например: `We need a value here`

Comment: @uorypm Любой. Тут вопрос больше в английском языке, поэтому специально не заострял на этом внимания. Так или иначе писать приходится на языках Java, C#, Python, JavaScript, TypeScript, ActionScript и изредка на C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ваш вариант вполне хорош, он описывает что делает функция, как будто мы объясняем её кому-то используя только комментарии:

```
/* Loads a file */
/* Processes the queue */
/* Opens a remote resource */
```

Второй вариант, который я встречал, это описание того, что мы *хотим* сделать этой функцией:

```
/* Load a file */
/* Process the queue */
/* Open a remote resource */
```

Эти два варианта самые частовстречающиеся, используйте любой, который предпочитаете лично.

Answer (score 3):

1. Используйте [Simplified Technical English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_Technical_English) (STE)
2. Пишите коммент как [commit message](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/GitCommitMessages#Examples_of_good_practice) в Git:

   - `Update default policies...`
   - `Add support for configuring...`
   - `Add shared_storage_test methods...`
   - `Add CPU arch filter...`
3. Следуйте модели "[50/72](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15324900/standard-to-follow-when-writing-git-commit-messages)":

   - Первая строка: длина первой строки - не более 50 символов
   - Вторая строка: пустая
   - Третья и следующие: длина ограничена 72 символами

Comment: `как комменты к коммитам в Git` – тут неясно, потому что комментарии к коммитам все пишут по-разному: кто-то пишет `add foo`, кто-то `added foo`.

Comment: Спасибо, @nick-volynkin , добавил примеры и ссылку на всеобъемлющий мануал